# How to modify Text widget's text property in FluidUI

Tags: text-editing, text-formatting

I intend to create some sketches of my application in [FluidUI](https://www.fluidui.com). However, when I add a Text widget, I can't modify the text property so its label is always 'Text'.

There are a few options, but setting text isn't one of them.

[image]

How can I modify the text?

Answer (score 0):

Double-click on the text to edit.

This wasn't obvious to me either!